# UIWebView history location

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using WebView and goBack is implemented with custom back button . When I navigate more than one request deep in the web view, when trying to hit back, I will flip-flop between the last request and current, instead of backing all the way back to the initial page (Home page).

My Questions

1) Where does web view history stored,
2) Am I able to see the url array list when i navigate more than one request,
3) May I know location of web view history stored in application sandbox.

Thanks.

Comment: check my edited answer . there are one demo code link check that demo code.

Comment: I wanted to know that How does UIWebView's canGoBack work , I think Web view stores url in some array list . I wanted to know more about that.

Comment: i have one way for store webview history . firstly create one array in your appdelegate and load webview so add that current link in that global array . you got it ? one by one loaded links add in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out sample: https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController

It is a drop-in inline browser for your iOS app.

Hope, It will helpful to you, Sir

:)

Comment: I wanted to know that How does UIWebView's canGoBack work , I think Web view stores url in some array list . I wanted to know more about that.